# How does BlueMix perform Autowiring during deployment?

Tags: java, boilerplate, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

I downloaded the BlueMix Java SQLDB Boilerplate and I am playing around with it, looking at extending for additional tables, etc.  I am a little confused at the 'autowiring' that happens which links the database services in BlueMix to the application at deployment/runtime.

Inside the boilerplate there is some configuration in the persistence.xml that says:

```
<persistence-unit name="openjpa-todo">
        <!-- The cloudAutowiring-1.0 Liberty feature will resolve this to whatever 
            the database service name is -->
        <!-- When running locally without this feature, create a datasource with 
            the JNDI name "jdbc/mydbdatasource" in server.xml -->
        <!-- If using MySQL locally then use the "url" property and append "?relaxAutoCommit=true", for example: 
            <dataSource id='mysql-datasource' jdbcDriverRef='mysql-driver' jndiName='jdbc/mydbdatasource'> 
                <properties user='root' password='password' url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?relaxAutoCommit=true"/> 
            </dataSource> -->
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/mydbdatasource</jta-data-source>
        <class>example.jpa.TODO</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- allow table definitions/creation on-the-fly jpa-2.0 feature -->
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
            <!-- allow table definitions/creation on-the-fly jpa-2.1 feature -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

How does BlueMix/Liberty map from the deployed services to the jta-data-source/persistence-unit?

Are there any conditions or requirements that need to be satisfied for the autowiring to take place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty cool.  During the deployment of the app the buildpack allows you to perfom some extra logic.  There is some logic in the Liberty buildpack that auto wires in a couple services.  Monitoring and Analytics, Logging, to just name a few.  The node buildpack does this as well.

I have captured some of the autowiring below.

```
2015-04-10T15:24:51.98-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v1.15-20150402-1422
2015-04-10T15:24:51.98-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Retrieving IBM 7.1.2_sr2fp11ifx-20150312 JRE (ibm-java-jre-7.1-2.11-pxa6470_27sr2fp11ifx-20150312_01-sfj.tgz) ... (0.0s)
2015-04-10T15:24:52.82-0400 [STG]     OUT          Expanding JRE to .java ... (0.8s)
2015-04-10T15:24:52.82-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Retrieving App Management Agent 2015.03.09_101422 (com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.app-mgmt-proxy-agent.zip) ... (0.0s)
2015-04-10T15:24:52.92-0400 [STG]     OUT          Expanding App Management to .app-management (0.0s)
2015-04-10T15:24:52.92-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Retrieving com.ibm.ws.liberty-2015.3.0.0-201504021422.tar.gz ... (0.0s)
2015-04-10T15:24:53.74-0400 [STG]     OUT          Installing archive ... (0.8s)
2015-04-10T15:24:53.76-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Retrieving com.ibm.ws.liberty.ext-2015.3.0.0-201504021422.tar.gz ... (0.0s)
2015-04-10T15:24:54.15-0400 [STG]     OUT          Installing archive ... (0.3s)
2015-04-10T15:24:54.33-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Retrieving and installing client jar(s) from com.ibm.ws.icap.clientJars.cloudant.zip (0.1s)
2015-04-10T15:24:54.34-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Auto-configuration is creating config for service instance 'Cloudant NoSQL DB-wr' of type 'cloudantNoSQLDB'
2015-04-10T15:24:54.36-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Liberty buildpack is done creating the droplet
2015-04-10T15:24:54.63-0400 [STG]     ERR 
2015-04-10T15:25:06.80-0400 [STG]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (147M)
```

What the buildpacks look for is bound services to your app.  If there are bound services such as Cloudant or Monitoring and Analytics it will add in the correct resources.  For Cloudant since it is JDBC, it will create the JDBC connection for you.

Additionally, the Liberty buildpack provides automatic configuration for the following service types: SQL Database ClearDB MySQL Database MySQL ElephantSQL PostgreSQL Cloudant™ NoSQL Database MongoLab dashDB Data Cache Session Cache MQ Light Monitoring and Analytics Auto-Scaling Single Sign On New Relic

Comment: Thanks I also found some additional information in the docs - https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#automaticconfigurationofboundservices it defines a full list of autowired services as: The Liberty buildpack provides automatic configuration for the following service types:
SQL Database
ClearDB MySQL Database
MySQL
ElephantSQL
PostgreSQL
Cloudant™ NoSQL Database
MongoLab
dashDB
Data Cache
Session Cache
MQ Light
Monitoring and Analytics
Auto-Scaling
Single Sign On
New Relic

Comment: added that to the answer so it can be found easier

Comment: Cloudant is not JDBC compatible. It offers a client library for Java that utilizes a REST API. The answer should be corrected as it is misleading to believe that cloudant can be configured as a data source with the application server via JDBC/JPA.